# Maximum number of commutators required to generate an element of the derived subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group for which the center $Z(G)$ is of index $n$.

**How to prove that an element of the derived subgroup $G^\prime$ is the product of at most $n^3$ commutators?**

This exercise is from a French algebra book of the 70s.

It follows another exercise asking to prove that if $G$ is a group whose center $Z(G)$ is of index $n$, then for any elements $x,y \in G$
$$[x,y]^{n+1}=[x,y^2][yxy^{-1},y]^{n-1}$$

Comment: Where does this exercise come from?

Comment: A French book on Algebra from the 70s.

Comment: It is really difficult to provide any useful help with this question. The intended solution will make use of results proved in the book coming before the exercise, and possibly on previous exercises in the book. But people here have no means of knowing what they are.

Comment: @DerekHolt This exercise follows another one that I included in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first step is to prove that there are at most $n^2$ distinct commutators. Let $N = Z(G)$, and choose elements $g_1, \dots, g_n$, one in each coset of $G/N$, so $g_1N, \dots, g_nN$ form a partition of $G$. Then for any $x, y$, we have $x \in g_iN$ and $y \in g_jN$ for some $i, j$, hence there are some $h, k \in Z(G)$ such that $x = g_i h$ and $y = g_j k$. Using this, we have
$$[x, y] = x^{-1}y^{-1}xy = h^{-1} g_i^{-1} k^{-1} g_j^{-1} g_i h g_j k = h^{-1}hk^{-1}k g_i^{-1} g_j^{-1} g_i g_j = [g_i, g_j]$$
so every commutator is of the form $[g_i, g_j]$ for some $i, j$.

Now, let $g \in G'$, so $g$ can be expressed as a product of commutators, let $m$ be the minimum length of an expression of $g$ as a product of commutators, and let
$$g = c_1 c_2 \cdots c_m$$
be an expression of $g$ as a product of commutators of length $m$. Suppose $m > n^3$. Then at least one of the $n^2$ commutators, say $a$, appears in this product at least $n+1$ times, so we can write
$$g = h_0 a h_1 a h_2 a \cdots a h_n a h_{n+1}$$
where each $h_i$ is a (possibly empty) product of commutators. From here, the idea is that by "swapping" we can "drag" the $a$'s in this product to the front. Note that $a^{-1}[x, y]a = [a^{-1}xa, a^{-1}ya]$, so in particular, for any commutator $c$, there is another commutator $c'$ for which $ca = ac'$. Similarly, if $h$ is a product of $r$ commutators, then there is another $h'$ which is a product of $r$ commutators for which $ha = ah'$. Thus we can write
\begin{align*}
g 
&= h_0 a h_1 a h_2 a \cdots a h_n a h_{n+1} \\
&= a h_0' h_1 a h_2 a \cdots a h_n a h_{n+1} \\
&= a^2 h_0'' h_1' h_2 a \cdots a h_n a h_{n+1} \\
&\,\,\vdots \\
&= a^{n+1} h_0^* h_1^* h_2^* \cdots h_n^* h_{n+1}
\end{align*}
where at each step we have kept the length of the product constant. But assuming the previous exercise you mentioned, $a^{n+1}$ can be written as a product of $n$ commutators, so $g$ can be written as a product of $m-1$ commutators, contradicting minimality. Thus $m \leq n^3$.